# Code snippets editor for developers in a web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

I was asked to create a configuration web interface for a set of configurable C# code snippets. This interface will be used massively by our company's developers.

Our company codding standard is ASP.NET / C# and all developers' IDE is Visual Studio. I figured out the best way to keep their developing experience unchanged is to actually open the snippets in Visual Studio, however I am afraid this is not even technically possible.

I also thought of using some highlighting libraries, however it will solve only the coloring problem, but not the rest of what the usual C# IDE offers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need an interface for creating code snippet ?

Comment: Yes, while keeping developing experience as untouched as possible. @Krishna